Using aliased variable in Cypress
In my cypress test I'm trying to store contents of id_px_file_input-field and then use it a part of cy.contains()
cy.get('[id=id_px_file_input]').then(new_id => {
    const tableID = new_id;
    cy.wrap(tableID).as('tableID');
}); 
cy.contains('Hakemisto').click()
cy.wait(10000)
cy.contains(`U ${'@tableID'} -`).click()
cy.wait(10000)

Where the input looks like this:
<input type="text" name="px_file_input" value="13bu" class="form-control" placeholder="" maxlength="400" disabled="" id="id_px_file_input">

and '13bu' is the value I want to store in "variable" tableID.
After clicking "Hakemisto" I want to test that the page contains an element with text U 13bu -
How can I do it ?

Use the static option when saving the tableId. This preserves the actual value, does not re-query if "Hakemisto" click re-writes the page.
Use invoke('val') to get the actual value, the element is not useful in .contains().
Then retrieve the value after the click, use it in next .contains().
Finally move wait(10_000) to timeout on the last click, so you're not waiting more than is necessary.
cy.get('[id=id_px_file_input]')
  .invoke('val')                   // value of input element, not the element itself
  .as('tableId', { type: 'static' });     // static alias storage 

cy.contains('Hakemisto').click()

cy.get('@tableId').then(tableID => {                         // retrieve value
  cy.contains(`U ${tableId} -`, {timeout: 10_000}).click()  // timeout 10 seconds
})

Using the cypress-aliases package
There is a package bahmutov/cypress-aliases that lets you unwrap aliases directly in the .contains() selector.
So this should work
import 'cypress-aliases'

it('my test description', () => {

  cy.get('[id=id_px_file_input]').invoke('val')                   
    .as('tableId', { type: 'static' });   

  cy.contains('Hakemisto').click()

  cy.contains('@tableId'), {timeout: 10_000}).click()
})


is this cy.contains(U ${'@tableId'} -) really working syntax ? It was just my guess... At least it did not work – (pls note, that the outer apostrophe-like things disppeared when saving my edits...)

No, it's a cut/paste boo-boo, the variable shouldn't be in quotes. Can happen when not actually writing code in an IDE or running it.
